# make sure all lines in a textfiles don't have the same value

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh, aix

I have a text file that contain multiple lines. Some of the lines have contain same value. What I want is to make sure that all of the lines do not have duplicates or "triplicates".

Sample:

```
2014-11-21
2013-10-19
2013-06-09
2014-11-21
2014-11-21
2015-02-19
2012-08-12
2015-07-22
2013-06-09
```

Output:

```
 2014-11-21
 2013-10-19
 2013-06-09
 2015-02-19
 2012-08-12
 2015-07-22
```

I tried `uniq` but it completely removes all the lines with duplicates. What I wanted is retain one.

Comment: `uniq` specifically needs its input sorted (so duplicates are on subsequent lines), so if you `sort file | uniq` you will get all duplicates removed (but the order sorted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sort` (it will also sort the output):

```
sort -u file
```

With `awk` (it doesn't sort, just filter out the duplicates, like the desired output):

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

With `perl` (same principle as the `awk` one):

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++' file
```

Comment: With `grep -n '' <file | sort -t: -uk2 | sort -t: -nk1,1 | cut -d: -f2-` the original order can be restored, as well.